# php to angular, keep array data

Tags: php, angular

I have my `php` code which save my db data into array. Then I use `json_encode` to send it to angular.

In Angular, I am using `httpClient` with the get method the get my data. But I got the data in many `objects` instead of `array` as I format it in my `php` code.

I have tried to use `JSON.parse` in angular with my `responseData` but I got error. I'd like to keep my `array` or `array` (from `php`) since I need to use `*ngFor` in `angular` which works only with array.

phpcode :

```
$q=mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT user_id FROM USER WHERE type='joueur'
"); 

while ($row=mysqli_fetch_object($q)){
    $result[]=$row;

}

foreach($result as $key => $re) {

    $id = $re -> user_id;
    $get_matinal = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT MATINAL.*, USER.nom, USER.prenom FROM MATINAL
    INNER JOIN USER 
    ON USER.user_id = MATINAL.user_id 
    WHERE USER.user_id = $id
    ");  

    $while_index = 0;
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_object($get_matinal)) {
        $get_matinal_resultat[$id]['DataSet']['data'][$while_index] = $row -> moyenne_fatigue;
        $get_matinal_resultat[$id]['DataSet']['label'] = 'indice';
        $get_matinal_resultat[$id]['Label'][$while_index] = $row -> created_at;
        $while_index = $while_index + 1;

    }

}

echo json_encode($get_matinal_resultat); 
echo mysqli_error($mysqli);
```

angular code :

```
this.http.get(this.server + 'getMatinal.php').subscribe(resData => {
  this.full_graph = resData;
  console.log(this.full_graph);
})
```

Here is the console log

[image]

So I got object of object whereas in php I did array of array. I'd like to keep the "attribute" since it's a "indexed array", but then I need to have some arrays and not objects..

Hope I have explained it correctly.

UPDATE :

Here is what I'd like to get as a result :

```
this.full_graph = 
[
  {
    user_id : '9',
    dataset: [{data:[2,4,3,3,5], label:'indice'}],
    label: ['1','2','3','4','5']
  },
  {
    user_id : '15',
    dataset: [{data:[2,4,3,3,5], label:'indice'}],
    label: ['1','2','3','4','5']
  },
]
```

Thanks

Comment: javascript doesn't support associative array, so those are converted into objects. If you can include expected output, we can help.

Comment: Thank you for answering @JitendraYadav. I have updated my post with the result I'd like

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some of the key points to note while creating array equivalent to JavaScript.

- Array with numeric index starting from 0, 1, 2... and so on will be equivalent to JavaScript array too.
- If you need a constant value inside an array, don't loop over it, just set it outside loop like `label in dataset index`.
- Don't use `id` as index, it will create objects due to non sequential values.

```
$response = [];

$q=mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT user_id FROM USER WHERE type='joueur'"); 

while ($row  =mysqli_fetch_object($q)){
    $userData = [];
    $userData['user_id'] = $row->user_id;

    $get_matinal = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT MATINAL.*, USER.nom, USER.prenom 
       FROM MATINAL
       INNER JOIN USER ON USER.user_id = MATINAL.user_id 
        WHERE USER.user_id = $row->user_id
    ");  

    $while_index = 1;
    $matinal_result = [];
    $labels = [];
    while($matinal = mysqli_fetch_object($get_matinal)) {
        $labels[] = $while_index;     // if want created_at use $matinal->created_at
        $matinal_result[] = $matinal->moyenne_fatique;
        $while_index = $while_index + 1;
    }

    $userData['Dataset'][] = ['data' => $matinal_result , 'label' => 'indice'];
    $userData['label'] = $labels;
  
    $response[] = $userData;
}

echo json_encode($response);
```